# JButton keep position in the center

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

So I'm making sample GUI using outer and inner class. I made a two inner classes. First the parent class which is the "first panel" second I made a child class which is the "second panel" where I add the JButton using GridBagLayout. My problem is it wont move in the location I want. I assigned my gridx = 2 and gridy = 1. But it won't move. Any help will appreciate thanks!

```
public class Login extends JFrame{

mainPanel mainpanel = new mainPanel(); // I create a class object for mainPanel so I can set as ContentPane.

//Constructor
public Login(){
    setSize(500,400);
    setTitle("Login Sample");
    setVisible(true);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    getContentPane().add(mainpanel);

    //Window Listener
    addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter(){
       public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e){
           System.exit(0);
       }//window Closing
       });
}
class mainPanel extends JPanel { //InnerClass

firstPanel firstpanel = new firstPanel();

//Constructor
public mainPanel(){
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension (500,400));
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.green, 3));
    add(firstpanel);
}

class firstPanel extends JPanel{

    //Create Button
    JButton loginButton = new JButton("Login");
    //Constraints
    GridBagConstraints loginConstraints = new GridBagConstraints();

    public firstPanel(){
        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        loginConstraints.gridx = 1;
        loginConstraints.gridy = 2;
        add(loginButton,loginConstraints);
    }
}
```

Comment: You have not specified what position you want the button to be in, or at what position it is in now. My guess is that it's centered in the middle if you only have one object in the middle of a BorderLayout.

Comment: I already specified the position using FIRST_LINE_START but it didn't move to upper left. Did I miss something? Thankyou.

Comment: @MiaLegaspi You can only accept one solution per question posted. You may accept the solution which helped you most.

Comment: @user3437460 oh I see. Thankyou for the tips I'll keep this :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First i want to say that if you just have a component and want it centered, its easy to use BorderLayout and add it(the component) "Center" to the parent. The GridbagLayout is not working like this since you dont have components in gridx = 0 and gridy = 0. The grid is calculated by the components size inside. When you want to do it with the GridBagLayout you have to configure more e.g.

> anchor:
>   Used when the component is smaller than its display area to determine where (within the area) to place the component. Valid values (defined as GridBagConstraints constants) are CENTER (the default), PAGE_START, PAGE_END, LINE_START, LINE_END, FIRST_LINE_START, FIRST_LINE_END, LAST_LINE_END, and LAST_LINE_START.

But i think its to much effort for i guess you want to do:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html

Comment: I'm experimenting using this GridBagLayout. I want to do is to put it in the upper left. Using anchor = GridBagConstraints.FIRST_LINE_START. But still in the middle? Did I miss something? Thanks

Comment: One thing i see is that you forget to pass the constraint for BorderLayout -> add(firstPanel,"Center")

Comment: The other thing is, that your inner panel has no size so, i would suggest that it has the same size as its content. To debug i suggest you to set backgroundColors to your components so you can check the expected layouting behaviour for all of them

Comment: Its already working I set the weightx and y to 0.5; The position of button already move. Thankyou!

Answer (score 3):

> JButton keep position in the center

The reason your JButton keeps centering itself to the center of the Frame has nothing to with inner class. Every container (e.g. JPanel, JFrame) has a default layout.

The default layout of JPanel is FlowLayout. Under this layout, all components added will be arranged in a linear fashion in a row for as much as possible the panel width can fit. Anything more than the panel's width will be pushed to the next row. The default alignment of flow layout used by the JPanel is `FlowLayout.CENTER`, that is why when you only add one button, it always center itself.

Since it has a layout governing the positioning of your components, attempts to change the components' positions may become futile.

> My problem is it wont move in the location I want. I assigned my gridx = 2 and gridy = 1. But it won't move

If you want your components to move to a specific location specified by you, you can set the layout to `null` (absolute positioning). However by doing so, you will have to set the location of every components which is added by you manually. If not, the components will not even show up in the frame.

To set a panel's layout to null, you may do this:

```
JPanel pnlMain = new JPanel();
pnlMain.setLayout(null);
```

To set the location of the components, we can use `setBounds()`:

```
JButton btn = new JButton();
btn.setBounds(x, y, width, height); //set location and dimension
```

---

However, setting containers' layout to `null` can give you many unforeseen problems. With the layout being removed and all positioning being hard coded, you are left with little or no control when your program are used in different systems and environment. Various usage by users can also cause unforeseen problems as well (e.g. When user resize your window).

Comment: I think this is the best method which I use. Which more clear to me. Thankyou so much!